# How to add response to alert blade template?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

in my UserController I have the following line:

```
        if (!Gate::check('can:main_page')) {
            return response(['error' => ['status' => 403, 'message' => 'You can't access this page']], 403);
        }
```

then in the template of the controller I have

```
@include('permissionAlert')
```

and The permissionAlert is defined like this

```
<style>
    .alert {
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 0;
       right: 0;
       margin-bottom: 15px;
       margin-right: 15px;
       z-index: 111;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#error-alert').alert('close');
    }, 5000);
</script>

@if (isset($errorMessage))
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="error-alert">
    <strong>Error! </strong> {!! $errorMessage !!}
</div>
@endif
```

My question is how can I add the message from the response in the controller to the alert blade template without passing again all the variables in the parent template it is being included in ?

Answer (score 0):

All variables will be available in the included view. [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#including-subviews)

> Blade's @include directive allows you to include a Blade view from within another view. All variables that are available to the parent view will be made available to the included view

```
// Controller
return view('welcome', ['message' => 'Alert info']);

// parent.blade.php
{{ $message }} // Alert info
@include('alert')


// alert.blade.php
{{ $message }} // Alert info
```